# Display data in two columns c++

Tags: c++, arrays, tabular

I am trying to display the same data but in two columns, so after school week 19, the data should be displayed in the columns to the right of the table until the total school weeks is reached i.e. 36. Below is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int const schoolWeeks = 37;
string week[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
int num = 0;

int main()
{
cout << left << setw(9) << setfill(' ') << "Week " << left << setw(9) << setfill(' ')<< "Menu" << left << setw(9) << setfill(' ') << "Week " << "Menu" << endl;
for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
{   
    cout << left << setw(9) << setfill(' ')<< i << week[num] << endl;

    num = num + 1;
    if (num == 4)
    {
        num = 0;
    }

}
for (int i = 20; i < schoolWeeks; i++)
{
    cout << left << setw(9) << setfill(' ') << i << week[num] << endl;

    num = num + 1;
    if (num == 4)
    {
        num = 0;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Why your **second** `for` is outside the **main**?

Answer (score 0):

Standard output with `std::cout` is based on the idea of a *stream* of data. Remember, it's called "io**stream**" for a reason. This means once you have written something to `std::cout`, you simply cannot "go back" a few lines and add something.

Consider piping in a Linux shell or on the Windows command line. It's possible to redirect the output of your program to be the input of another program, which could then do any imaginable thing with it, e.g. sending it over the internet:

```
myprogram.exe > otherprogram.exe
```

How could you possibly add something to an already written line in such a scenario?

Considering all of this, it becomes clear that the only viable solution is to know in advance the contents of every line. You cannot wait until line 19 before thinking about the second column, you must do it right away. In other words, first print week 1 and week 19, then week 2 and week 20, then week 3 and week 21, and so on. See the pattern? It's always *"week X in column one, week X+18 in column two"*. And that's pretty much the solution.

Here's a quickly written loop adhering to the style of your existing code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
{   
    cout << left << setw(9) << setfill(' ')<< i << week[num]
         << left << setw(9) << setfill(' ') << " " << (i + 18) << " "
         << left << setw(9) << setfill(' ') << " " << week[num]
         << endl;

    num = num + 1;
    if (num == 4)
    {
        num = 0;
    }
}
```

The manipulators like `std::setw` or `std::setfill` could probably use some improvement, but the point is that:

1. The loop only counts from 1 to 18.
2. The body performs the output for `i` *and* for `i + 18`.

Comment: Thank you, there seems to be small problem with the week counter, it resets after reaching 19 or the first week on the second column, it should be CDABCD but it starts ABCDABCD. I have tried to add 2 to the num counter but it skips the first letters AB and instead displays CD..CD..CD etc. Is it not possible to continue with the counter in the new column without reseting the week lettering i.e ABCD?

Comment: @user3057164: This sounds as if you have written a new program based on a new idea (the one explained in my answer). I suggest you just ask a new question with the relevant code that does not work, because it's really a new problem, isn't it?