# Lining up columns in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to line up columns using the standard `<iostream>` library and nothing else (so I can't use `std::setw`, this is for a school exercise).

This is currently my code:

```cpp
cout << endl;
cout << number_1 << endl;
cout << number_2 << " x" << endl;
cout << "--" << endl;
cout << number_3 << endl;
cout << number_4 << " +" << endl;
cout << "---" << endl;
cout << number_5 << endl;
```

It outputs things like this:

```
35
67 x
--
245
2100 +
---
2345
```

As you can see, the 245 and 2100 do not line up correctly. The 245 can be a 2-digit number, too (for eg: 45).

Is there any way I can line it up for those possibilities like this, using only the `<iostream>` library?

```
  35
  67 x
  --
 245
2100 +
 ---
2345
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185678/display-data-in-two-columns-c

Comment: @NathanOliver the linked answer uses `std::setw` which the OP cannot use, and for a good reason. The answer mentions `std::setfill`, but I guess OP can't use that either. :/

Comment: @NathonOlver Can't use std::setw sadly enough :/

Comment: Do note that `cin` has `width` and `fill` member functions that is what `setw` and `setfill` call.  You can just call thos member functions youself instead of using the functions from `<iomanip>`

Comment: If you can't use `width` either, you can just pre-calculate the number of spaces: `if (x > 999) spaces = 0; else if (x > 99) spaces = 1;....` Then print that number of spaces. (Or use `log10()`)

Comment: "standard <iostream> library and nothing else" implies that you can use width since it is part of the <iostream> header.  What were the exact instructions?  Did it say the only item in the std namespace that was allowed as cout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set max width and align right

```
cout.width(4); cout << right << "245"<< endl;
cout.width(4); cout << right << "2100" << endl;
```

---

But...the solution expected by your teacher is this:

```
string cout_width(int w, string s){
    
    int len = s.length();
    while(len++ < w)
        s.insert(0, " ");

    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    int width = 4;
    
    cout << cout_width(width, "245") << endl;
    cout << cout_width(width, "2100") << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yep, `cout.width(4);` is does the exact same thing as `cout << setw(4);`, but doesn't require `<iomanip>`.

Comment: Not sure if the teacher will like this even though it does not use setw()

Comment: @drescherjm Since the teacher didn't explicitly disallow it, at least they'll learn something :)